# How can I get value in select vue.js? vue.js 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My case is like this

I have a component like this :

```
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default panel-filter">
        ...
            <div id="collapse-location" class="collapse in">
                <!-- province -->
                <div style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                    <location-bs-select element-name="province_id" level="provinceList" type="1" module="searchByLocation"/>
                </div>
                <!-- city -->
                <location-bs-select element-name="city_id" level="cityList" type="2" module="searchByLocation"/>
            </div>

            <!-- button search -->
            <div class="panel-item">
                <br>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-block btn-success" v-on:click="searchData">
                    Search
                </a>
            </div>
        ...
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        ...
        data() {
            return{
                ...
                province_id:'',
            }
        },
        ...
        methods: {
            ...
            searchData: function() {
                console.log(this.province_id)
                console.log(document.getElementsByName("province_id")[0].value)
                console.log('testtt')
            } 
        }
    }
</script>
```

The component have child component, that is location-bs-select. The component used to display provincy and city

The component child like this :

```
<template>
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected" :name="elementName" @change="changeLocation">
        <template v-for="option in options">
            <template>
                <option v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>
            </template>
        </template>
    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['elementName', 'level','type','module'],
        ...
    };
</script>
```

If I do inspect element, the result like this :

[image]

When click button search, I want to get the value of province and city

I try javascript like this :

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName("province_id")[0].value)
```

it works

But I want to use vue step. I try like this :

```
console.log(this.province_id)
```

It does not work

How can I solve it?

Comment: where do you call `this.provinsi_id` ? where is your `selected` defined ? You did not add your data property in the code sample. Why is your option wrapped in two templates? Just loop on the option directly

Comment: @Frank Provost, Sorry. I had update my question

Comment: @Frank Provost, location-bs-select component used by some component. Not only used by one component. So I separate it

Comment: sorry I think you misunderstood. Even though there was a typo - what is actually relevant is WHERE in your code do you call `this.province_id` ? From a method? in the created? after a select?

Comment: @Frank Provost, From name of select. Look at my image

Comment: ah I see - I think I understood - let me quickly write an answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got you right. You want to propagate the value of the select back to the parent. The Child component COULD be like this.

- removed template nesting
- added change event listener and emit method
- added data

And all together:

```
<template>
    <select @change="emitChange" class="form-control" v-model="selected" :name="elementName">

        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id" >{{ option.name }}</option>

    </select>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: ['elementName', 'level','type','module'],
        data: function() {
            return { selected: null } 
        },
        methods: {
            emitChange: function() {
                this.$emit('changeval', this.selected);
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Now your parent needs to listen to this emit. Here just the relevant parts of your parent

```
...

<location-bs-select element-name="city_id" 
                    level="cityList" 
                    type="2" 
                    @changeval="changeval"
                    module="searchByLocation"/>


 ...

methods: {
   changeval: function(sValue) {

      this.province_id = sValue;
      console.log(this.province_id);

   }
}
```

Quickly summed up

- the select value is bound to the selected prop of your data
- the select has an attached change event which will emit changes
- the parent will listen to this emit and will update it's relevant data prop

Comment: Two `@change`. `@change="emitChange"` and `@change="changeLocation"`. Whether both can work at once?

Comment: oh sorry - i didn't notice the already existing @change. Simply remove the one that does not fit into this exampe (changeLocation) - in your sample the changeLocation method didn't exist - i removed it from my answer

Comment: No problem. I use `@change="changeLocation"`. It used to filter city by province

Comment: Then you should just combine the the method bodies